# KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I'm working on a project. Today I started getting this error: "KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?".

I've seen another post here on stackoverflow, that this is a problem with NODE14 and knex < 8.0.3. I'm not using this version, so I don't understand where this error is coming from? Here's some relevant info:

"dependencies": {
"knex": "^0.95.13",
"mysql": "^2.18.1",
"next": "12.0.3",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2"
}

Here is some relevant code:

**knexFile.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3000,
      user: process.env.MYSQL_USERS,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
    },
    debug: true,
    pool: {
      max: 50,
      min: 2
    },
  }
};
```

Can someone help me with this issue? The error comes and goes and I don't know how to solve this. Thanks!